# NuGet PackageReference BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies in .NET 4.8 Installer projects use output group of ref directory instead of lib assemblies

Tags: .net, package, nuget, ref, lib

I migrated NuGet packages in a project developed with .NET Framework 4.8 from packages.config to PackageReference.

In the Installer project, the System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll file is included from the ref assembly instead of the lib assembly.

How can I ensure that the file from the lib assembly is used?

I am expecting a solution that ensures the packages included in the Installer project are used from the lib assembly instead of the ref assembly.